# End-to-Edge Protection on DirectAccess

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, direct-access

Learning about DirectAccess.

This is a diagram of End-to-Edge protection

[image]

Once the data goes in the corporate network, it doesn't matter whether the corporate network is running on IPv4 or IPv4. Is my understanding correct, or does the corporate network have to support IPv6, regardless of whether this is end-to-edge protection, or end-to-end protection.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the upvote .... can someone answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corporate network must have IPv6 support, according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637767(v=ws.10).aspx

> For end-to-edge protection, as shown in Figure 3, DirectAccess clients
>   establish an IPsec session to an IPsec gateway server (which by
>   default is the same computer as the DirectAccess server). The IPsec
>   gateway server then forwards unprotected traffic, shown in red, to
>   application servers on the intranet. This architecture does not
>   require IPsec on the intranet and works with any **IPv6-capable
>   application servers.**